# Relation between a packet and a frame over the network

Tags: networking, ip, mac-address, packet, frame

I am learning how networks work and I have a question. What is actually sent over the network? A packet/datagram or a frame?

I believe it is a packet. If so, let's say Computer A wants to communicate with Computer B which is in another country for example. Computer A encapsulates its data in a segment, which is encapsulated in a packet, which in turn is encapsulated in a frame. When is the frame decapsulated?

My interpretation so far is that the frame is decapsulated before leaving the LAN which leaves a packet to be sent to Computer B over the "network". I am not sure my interpretation is correct.

Also, what are the MAC source and destination addresses that Computer A write in the frame it produces?

Comment: Weird, OSI-Model  seems like the perfect tag here, but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet#Terminology) "packet" is normally used at the IP layer, and segment (TCP) or datagram (UDP) are used at the higher transport layer.

It's common to refer to Ethernet frames, rather than Ethernet packets, so I think your 2nd-last paragraph is correct.

MAC addresses are used to identify network interfaces at the data link layer, for devices which share the same physical medium (such as a switched Ethernet network). In your example, Computer A would use:

- **Source MAC**: the MAC address of the physical network interface (within Computer A) used to send the Ethernet frame.
- **Destination MAC**: [is likely to be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3244003/57743) the MAC address of the default gateway on the LAN, which provides access to the external network.

The segment/datagram should only be decapsulated fully when it arrives at Computer B.

Comment: Thanks! It is clearer. Another question : What does a router send to another router in the network? A frame or a packet?

Comment: A router would normally [forward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)#Forwarding) an IP packet to another router.

Comment: As I read on the subject, it seems like a router recreates a frame.

Comment: @Gradient Yes, I think that's right. Although a router will *forward* packets at the IP layer, the packet must be encapsulated in a frame in order for it to leave the router's physical interface. The destination router will decapsulate the frame on arrival.